# Combining 3 charts into 1

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

How can I combine the 3 charts into 1 in Data Studio?

I'd like the left hand axis to be number of users, and right hand axis to be %.

Also, after combining all 3 charts, can I still include a reference line? (I'd like the reference line to be for the % chart).

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by:

1. **Selection**: Select all three [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) charts;
2. **Blend data**: Right click on one of the selected charts and click on `Blend data` from the drop-down;
3. **Right Y-Axis**: Click on the newly created chart, and from the *Style Tab*, set the *Axis* of the `Percentage Metric` to **Right Y-Axis** (leave the other 2 Metrics as the default, Left Y-Axis), along with the [Reference line](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9921462).

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/734fa07f-50d0-4b1c-ab9d-9a7592be6c5c) (Sample Google Analytics Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]